# Remember-me functionality for Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, remember-me

Here is the issue:

We have to implement two-step login process. First step - user enters name/password and is being authenticated. Second step - user may be presented with secondary select screen where he chooses an option via simple click. When this is done user is finally authorized for certain set of actions. This concludes authentication/authorization process for current user session.

We do use Spring Security in its standard form: first login screen is handled by default Spring Security stack and as soon as user is in - Spring considers the login process done.

The secondary selection screen is completely outside of Spring Security and all we do upon user selection is set the properly configured object back into security context. This works for current session as expected.

We do have remember-me functionality as well which is implemented via checkbox named _spring_security_remember_me in the first login screen and also an overridden UserDetailsService bean.

The remember-me works fine for as long as there is no secondary select screen option. Since the secondary screen has nothing to do with Spring Security, the remember-me mechanism would not be activated for secondary option and all it is capable of is to remember only the first login step. This results with having to ask remembered user the option and we are tasked to avoid this.

Having both login form and secondary selection on the same page is not an option.

We could use additional cookie if the secondary selection is required and based on that cookie "silently" pass the needed parameter when authenticating. But this would mean that we have to do bunch of manual stuff which Spring Security "ought" to offer, also this puts some security logic and tokens outside of Spring managed security and remember-me functionality.

So here is the question to security gurus: how to "force" remember-me functionality to accept the secondary presented option? If it was possible for Remember-Me filter to "inspect" the passed URL and identify that remember-me option is chosen, we could add this parameter. But this does not sound like it is possible.

Is it possible/feasible to use yet another login form on secondary screen and "silently" pass just needed additional parameters? I know we won't include the user name/password in this case, at least not in clear form. The option sounds like it can be done, but I am still believing that there might be an easier way to just force the Remember-Me to do what it does. Or is there?

Thanks,
Nikolay

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last selected option for each user in the database. Then you implement an [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html) that reads the stored option from the database and sets it in the security context. If the option is not found, the user is redirected to the selection screen.

This should work regardless of the authentication type (form, basic or remember-be) only if you are using Spring Security 3.1 or later, as the possibility to register an AuthenticationSuccessHandler has been introduced [in that version](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1603). There's a [discussion on this topic](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?97223-Remember-Me-Success-Handler) in the Spring Forums.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it looks more complicated than our DB design should be. I implemented this by embedding the username and the extra parameter in the login itself, so that RememberMe already contains all the values in a single token - this was the goal. The challenge was to figure out the "second" login form to actually trigger the the built-in login. That second login form actually have only hidden parameters and is operated by JavaScript (i.e. user does not get a clue that hi is being logged in again - he simply selects that additional value).

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to consider the submissal of the second screen an actual login. "Logging in" establishes a trusted session with an authenticated user. Everything else actually is a property of the users's session, NOT the authentication context. Can't you consider this second selection as a simple user configuration value that gets persisted? Also I can't follow your assumption that this would complicate your DB design: it's a simple table with three columns: username, key and value.